# Move file from application specific external storage to user selected directory by storage access framework on Android 11?

Tags: android, storage-access-framework, android-storage

How to move file
**from** directory `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files` returned by `Context.getExternalFilesDirs(null)`
**to** user selected directory `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AselectedDir` returned by `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` (which is `/storage/emulated/0/selectedDir`)?

Comment: You are asking too much. Start with code for creating a file in the directory obtained with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. And copy one file as a start. After that you can manage that copying in a loop.

Comment: Could you write a sample code to copy 1 file?

Comment: Can you create a file in the directory obtained with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE? If not then start with that. I advised that before.

Comment: `to user selected directory /storage/emulated/0/selectedDir returned by ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE?` That is nonsense as ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE will not give you a path like  /storage/emulated/0/selectedDir to begin with. Instead you get an uri.

Comment: Question was updated. I already have file ready to move in directory: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files`. Uri from `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE` I have too (`content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/tree/primary%3AselectedDir`)